# How to select and return custom properties from a TEntity based on a method parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, anonymous-function, anonymous-types

I'm working on an advanced Generic repository targeted `.Net 5` and `Entity Framework core`.

I'm trying to create a method that will receives the properties to be selected from a `TEntity` and this method should get those properties from the `table` and return a `list` of `object`s their structure is an `Anonymous type` contains the properties to be selected sent in the `parameters`.

**What I tried :**

```
public virtual object GetPartial<TEntity> ( params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] propertiesToBeSelected )
{
    var result = (from x in Context.Set<TEntity>() select propertiesToBeSelected).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

**How wanna the final use for this method :**
Let's imagin we have a `Student` entity and I want to select just a list of `name` and `city` from the `Student`, I want to use the method like this :

```
MyXRepo.GetPartial<Student>(x => x.Name, x => x.City);
```

I wish you understood, and sorry for my level in English.

I know this is no a correct way, **so please any help to fix this issue ?**

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv That doesn't really help. Please give constructive advice on how an appropriate solution will look like. I'm also using generic repositories handling specific types that only contain properties used for the current context. They work like a charm. But I'm also new to EFCore and any advice will help.

Comment: I know that does not help. But when I see generic repository pattern in solution which I have to improve, I'm really mad. DbSet is already repository, DbContext is already UoW. You can create just Extension method for IQueryable, that's it, no repositories are needed.

Comment: Answer for yourself, how do you plan to use returned `object`? Which type it should have? `ExpandoObject`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes DbSet and DbContext will contain most of the work. But they handle persistence objects. We're using AutoMapper to abstract business logic objects from persistence. That's the reason for custom generic repositories of BOs. And those repositories uses generics even for persistence objects to avoid creating one BO-repository per type.

Comment: Use Dynamic LINQ

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov please any more details ? and massive thanks

Comment: @SebastianSchumann I agree with you, I think **Svyatoslav** didn't worked on a huge projects, Generic repository is Anti-Pattern I know this, but sometimes generic repository helps me to clean my code and separate responsibilities he still have strong advantages.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I know that but not in all the situations the patterns should be followed to be a good, cute programmer sometimes you must break the rules to do what you want.

Comment: *advanced Generic repository*? What I see is unnecessary reinventing the wheel, because what are you asking already exists - it's called LINQ `Select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, I don't have a lot of experience and I won't try discuss which pattern is wrong or good :).

I agree, returned type should be rather `List<object>` than object itself and I prefer to add this kind of logic to extensions.

I've tested this code, try yourself and check if fits (of course, ignore controller types )

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    var result = myService.GetPartial<Company>(x=> new { x.Name1 , x.Notes});
    return Ok();
}
```

and the implementation

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetPartial<T>(Func<T, object> selector)
            where T:class
{
    var t = DbContext.Set<T>().Select(selector).ToList();
    return t;
}
```

Once again, it is my version what I understood. And it is little more flexible. Instead list of properties method get function returning object whatever type you want.You have to add some extra chars (lambda convention) and cast (if needed), but you can also get strongly typed object or create another implementation

```
IEnumerable<TModel> GetPartial<TEntity, TModel>(Func<TEntity, TModel>){...
```

Any improvements are welcome

Comment: I tested this solution, at now worked fine, Thank you so much

Comment: >The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted". [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: thank you so much this is the correct answer in my situation

Answer (score 0):

Why not use OData instead? That is a well defined standard already and would allow you to do exactly what you want. There is already a library available and should hook-up easily with entity framework back-end as it works on IQueryable types.